# Матрица выводит не то, что хотелось бы видеть :)

Tags: java, массивы, случайные-числа, матрицы

Господа, доброго времени суток. Такой вопрос: почему при помощи Random при выводе в консоль  матрица состоит из каких-то непонятных значений( причем, они все одинаковые), а при использовании того же Рандома для обычного числа, выводится действительно число, а не "хэшкод"

```
package ru.itpark;    
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static int array_NxM[][];    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите размер матрицы");
        System.out.print("Количество строк: ");
        int n=in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Количество столбцов: ");
        int m=in.nextInt();
        array_NxM= new int [n][m];
        Random random =new Random();
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
            for( int j=0; j<m; j++){
                array_NxM[i][j]= random.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                System.out.print(array_NxM+" ");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        int b=random.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(b);    
    }
}
```

Вот вывод:

```
Введите размер матрицы
Количество строк: 5
Количество столбцов: 5
[[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 
[[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 
[[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 
[[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 
[[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 [[I@6e0be858 

1155286982
```

Comment: Вы все время выводите одно и то же. `System.out.print(array_NxM[i][j]);`

Comment: Премного благодарен, а до этого я получается ссылки на массив выводил?

Comment: точно *(5 символов нужно...)*

Comment: Это глюк Матрицы, ясно же.

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо, Igor. Я неправильно выводил сам массив, надо не

```
System.out.print(array_NxM+" ");
```

а:

```
System.out.print(array_NxM[i][j]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Используйте `array_NxM[i][j] = (int)Math.random()*n` вместо `Random random =new Random();` где `n` - это верхняя граница.

```
public  class main  {

    static int array_NxM[][];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите размер матрицы");
        System.out.print("Количество строк: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Количество столбцов: ");
        int m = in.nextInt();
        array_NxM = new int [n][m];

        for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
            for( int j=0; j<m; j++){
                array_NxM[i][j]= (int)(Math.random()*10);
                System.out.print(array_NxM[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        int b=(int)(Math.random()*10);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(b);

    }

}
```

Весь код